# Matlab: Import .csv-file via textscan

Tags: matlab, csv, import, textscan

Im working on a program which shall manipulate .csv files from an Experiment. Therefore i want to use the command `textscan`, which sounds really suitable for my Problem. But I got problems with the implementation of the code. My code Looks like this:

```
fid = fopen('filename.csv'); 
data = textscan(fid, '%*s %f %f %f %f %f', 'delimiter', ';', 'headerlines', 3); 
fclose(fid);
```

For `fid` I get the value "4". I dont understand why i get a number. Shouldnt I get an cell Array of my file?
My file consists of 3 Header, 1 column with text and the rest are numbers.

Thank you very much in anticipation!
Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The `fid` is a file identifier, that is, a [number that is used to refer to that file](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html). That's the number you pass to `textscan` to read the file's contents. Those contents will be stored in `data`.